# How to update or return a sub document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a document like this.

```
{
    '_id': xxx,
    'name': xxx,
    'background': [],
    'songs': [
        {
            'title': xxx,
            'background': []
        }
    ]
}
```

First, how could i just return song document not all. I want something like this.

```
function(err, doc) {
    //the doc is {'title': xxx, 'background': []}
}
```

Second, how could i push a data in background array that doc is in songs.

```
collection.update(
    {'_id': xxx, songs: {$elemMatch:{'title': xxx}},
    {
         $push: {'background': xxx}
    }
)
```

This sample code always push the data to background of root doc not song doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit fields returned from a Mongo query through a [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/). This might look like

```
collection.find( { /*some criteria*/ }, { song: 1, _id:0 } )
```

To modify an element in an array within a document, you will need to use the [positional $ operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

```
collection.update( {'_id': xxx, songs: {$elemMatch:{'title': xxx}}, { $push: {'songs.$.background': xxx} }, callback )
```